# ¿cómo puedo convertir este código en una función asincrona?

Tags: javascript, array, reduce

El código que tengo es:

```
const personas = [
  { nombre: 'Edu', edad: 35 },
  { nombre: 'Manuel', edad: 37 },
  { nombre: 'Marta', edad: 42 },
  { nombre: 'Edu', edad: 25 },
];
```

Para resolverlo uso:

```
const busqueda = personas.reduce((acc, persona) => {
  acc[persona.nombre] = ++acc[persona.nombre] || 0;
  return acc;
}, {});
const duplicados = personas.filter( (persona) => {
    return busqueda[persona.nombre];
});

console.log(duplicados);
```

necesito convertir esta solución en una función que sea asincrona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getDuplicates() {

const busqueda = personas.reduce((acc, persona) => {
  acc[persona.nombre] = ++acc[persona.nombre] || 0;
  return acc;
}, {});

const duplicados = personas.filter( (persona) => {
    return busqueda[persona.nombre];
});

return duplicados;

}
```